# Delete a directory only if it exists using a shell script

Tags: shell

I have a shell (`ksh`) script. I want to determine whether a certain directory is present in `/tmp`, and if it is present then I have to delete it. My script is:

**test**

```
#!/usr/bin/ksh
# what should I write here?
if [[ -f /tmp/dir.lock ]]; then
    echo "Removing Lock"
    rm -rf /tmp/dir.lock
fi
```

How can I proceed? I'm not getting the wanted result: the directory is not removed when I execute the script and I'm not getting `Removing Lock` output on my screen.

I checked manually and the lock file is present in the location.
The lock file is created with `set MUTEX_LOCK "/tmp/dir.lock"` by a TCL program.

Comment: does the file exist in the directory?

Comment: Looks like you're having great confusion about what you're doing: you say you have a Tcl script (with an extension ending in `.tcl`), and at the same time you start it with the shebang (which is by the way wrong as it does not specify a full pathname but rather a relative one as you forgot the first slash) which tells the kernel to execute the script using `ksh` -- the Korn shell. There's so many confusion it's not even possible to deduce what you really intended to do.

Comment: And the script is obviously a Unix shell script, not a Tcl script.

Comment: @kostix : the script is just a sample script, already a developer has written this type of script (big) i need to extend some of the functionally..

Comment: If you are using `rm -rf`, there is no need to test for existence (other than to echo the message, and you might be happier just using `rm -rvf`).

Comment: @Amit0440, your remark seems to not address the points I made in any way: you asked about why a Korn shell command named `[[` does not work for you; your script is obviously *not* Tcl and you still insist it's somehow related to Tcl and returned back the "tcl" tag I removed. You might miss the point that questions on SO are separate; you might have this script be a part of bigger project involving Tcl, but *this* question has nothing to do with Tcl, and tags apply to particular questions, not concepts in your head.

Comment: @kostix the reason why i kept tag "tcl" due to i have the script which has the extension **.tcl** so it means for me that its a tcl script is int it?

Comment: @Amit0440, you have been told several times that the script being discussed is a Korn shell script, not a Tcl script. The extension of the file containing the script has absolutely nothing to do with how the script is interpreted -- this is Unix, not Windows. I wonder why you're so persistent. For instance, can you refer to a manual where the `[[` "Tcl" command is defined? (Hint: there's no such command in Tcl.)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

In addition to `-f` versus `-d` note that `[[ ]]` is not POSIX, while `[ ]` is. Any string or path you use more than once should be in a variable to avoid typing errors, especially when you use `rm -rf` which deletes with extreme prejudice. The most portable solution would be

```
DIR=/tmp/dir.lock
if [ -d "$DIR" ]; then
    printf '%s\n' "Removing Lock ($DIR)"
    rm -rf "$DIR"
fi
```

Comment: It's kind of strange to use `printf` like that. Any rationale? Why don't just do `echo "Removing Lock ($DIR)"`?

Comment: Because `printf` is the new echo, which is so nineties. No System V versus BSD madness, no -n and -c headaches, full formatting. Need I say more? :-)

Answer (score 4):

For directory check, you should use `-d`:

```
if [[ -d /tmp/dir.lock ]]; then
    echo "Removing Lock"
    rm -rf /tmp/dir.lock
fi
```